# Why use .update in MongooseJS / MongoDB?

Tags: mongoose

It seems that I can `.save` an existing document, so why would I use a `.update`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key benefit with `update` is that it allows you to modify a document atomically.

The canonical example is incrementing a numerical field of a document:

With `save`:

1. Call `findOne` to get the existing doc.
2. Modify the doc in memory to add one to the numerical field.
3. Call `save` to commit the change to the collection.

With `update`:

1. Call `update` using the `$inc` operator to read, modify, and commit in a single, atomic step.

Using `save` leaves open the possibility that another edit could occur during the three steps and then be overwritten by the `save` and lost.